# Nethereum External Signer (C#) extending EthExternalSignerBase issue with SignExternallyAsync

Tags: evm, nethereum, c#

I am currently having issues extending `EthExternalSignerBase`. I have an API that signs messages, similar to an Amazon KMS.

One of the issues I am running into is deriving the `ECDSASignature` response, always getting the below error which I believe implies an issue with my `r` `s` and `v` signature

`Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Could not construct a recoverable key. This should never happen.)`

My current theory is that I made need to serialize the transaction within the `message` field using some sort of `RLP` library, but I am not quite sure.

Current `SignExternallyAsync` function that is erroring within my `EthExternalSignerBase` implemented class

```
protected override async Task<ECDSASignature> SignExternallyAsync(byte[] bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Signing {bytes.ToHex()}");
    var uri = new Uri($"{baseURL}/sign/message");

    var data = new
    {
        walletId = this.walletId,
        chainType = "EVM",
        chainId = "1",
        message =  $"0x{bytes.ToHex()}"
    };

    // make http request
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // parse
    string signedMessage = doc.RootElement.GetProperty("signature").GetString()!;
    Console.WriteLine($"signedMessage: {signedMessage}");

    return ECDSASignatureFactory.FromComponents(signedMessage.HexToByteArray()).MakeCanonical();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

The error originates where it tries to find the recovery id, [see here](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum/blob/master/src/Nethereum.Signer/EthECKey.cs). The Nethereum code uses

- the ECDSASignature - which is what you return the `SignExternallyAsync` method,
- the hash - which is the `bytes` parameter of the `SignExternallyAsync` method, and
- the public key  *<-- this might be what you're missing!*

To provide the public key, you need to override the `GetPublicKeyAsync` method:

```
protected override async Task<byte[]> GetPublicKeyAsync()
{
    byte[] pubKeyBytes = your_pubkey_here;
    return pubKeyBytes;
}
```

**Important to note is that the public key needs to be formatted correctly.**

It depends what format Amazon KMS provides.  For example, an uncompressed public key should be the concatenated bytes of the X coordinate and Y coordinate AND prefixed with 04 to indicate that it is an uncompressed public key. Alternatively, the public key could be 'compressed' meaning it has only the X coordinate and prefixed with 02 or 03 depending on whether the Y coordinate is even or odd.  Read more about [public key formats here](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch04.asciidoc#public-key-formats).

So, if you were already providing a public key but still got this error, then might be you're missing something like the 04 prefix (as in my case)